# Failed to execute: 'control restart'

Tags: openshift, wildfly

I am trying to restart my application and I see the following error

[image]

I even tried this from Continuous deployment and see the same issue

```
remote: Preparing build for deployment        
remote: Deployment id is 34fb8db9        
remote: Activating deployment        
remote: Starting Postgres cartridge        
remote: Postgres started        
remote: Deploying WildFly        
remote: Starting wildfly cart        
remote: Timed out waiting for http listening port for wildfly process        
remote: -------------------------        
remote: Git Post-Receive Result: failure        
remote: Activation status: failure        
remote: Activation failed for the following gears:        
remote: 53f0dc0ce0b8cd0dc5000011 (Error activating gear: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to execute: 'control start' for /var/lib/openshift/53f0dc0ce0b8cd0dc5000011/wildfly)        
remote: Deployment completed with status: failure        
remote: postreceive failed        
To ssh://53f0dc0ce0b8cd0dc5000011@api-pennyapp.rhcloud.com/~/git/api.git/
   a02791c..837d20b  master -> master
```

No Idea on how to resolve this, any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the timeout in your RHC command.

`rhc app restart <yourappname> --timeout <seconds>`